# System of counting months in Noach

Tags: calendar, parashat-noach, mabul, months

Going through Noach with the help of Rashi, there are 3 different systems of counting months.

1. From (Tishrei|Nisan) [1](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.7.11?with=Rashi) [2](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.8.13?with=Rashi) [3](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.8.14?with=Rashi)
2. [From (Kisleiv|Sivan) when the rain stopped](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.8.4?with=Rashi)
3. [From (Cheshvan|Iyar) when the rain started](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.8.5?with=Rashi)

Why does the Torah use three different systems of counting within a single narrative?  And why does it use each one in those particular places?

Comment: Please cite the original verses. It is difficult to jump back and forth.

Comment: IIRC The Ramban tackles this and IIRC uses a single dating system for the entire narrative. So the question would be on Rashi, not the Torah.